# Returning the result of a Closure in php?

Tags: php

Somewhere in my `__call` magic method I'm invoking `transactional`, accepting a `Closure`:

```
try {
    $that = $this
    $this->conn->transactional(function ($conn) use ($that, $realMethod) {
        $result = call_user_func([$that, $realMethod], $conn);
        $this->conn->exec('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
    });
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->conn->exec('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');

    throw $e;
}
```

Is there any way to return `$result` from inside the Closure (or using pass by reference, etc.)?

Method `$conn->transactional` is **not under my control**:

```
public function transactional(Closure $func)
{
    $this->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $func($this);
        $this->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is -- create a local variable inside the `try` block and capture it by reference:

```
$result = null;
$that = $this;
$this->conn->transactional(function ($conn) use ($that, $realMethod, &$result) {
    $result = call_user_func([$that, $realMethod], $conn);
    $this->conn->exec('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
});

return $result;
```

Of course this assumes that `transactional` will call its argument on the spot, since that's the case indeed we can all be happy.

Comment: Figured it out right after posting the question. For some strange reason PHPStorm gave me an error, letting me think it wasn't possible. Thanks!!!